# Calculating rating based on multiple counts

Tags: algorithm, math, rating, scoring

May be it is easy to calculate but I am stuck in this from last two days. I have web application which generates number of top brands and number of low brands. Now I want to calculate the overall rating by considering these two counts. I tried using Bayesian algorithm but it didn't fit. If I find only one top brand it gives high rating. Most of the time I end up getting either one high brand or low brand alone, which wont justify overall rating. When I get both in good number it works fine. Here is what I tried in my angular 2 code ,

`

```
    var TBS = 4;
    var LBS = 2;

    var totalTopBrands = this.totalHighBrandCount ;
    var totalLowBrands = this.totalLowBrandCount;



    // var rating = 0;
     var totalBrandCount =totalTopBrands + totalLowBrands;
    // if(totalBrandCount !== 0){
    //     rating = ((TBS * totalTopBrands) + ( LBS * totalLowBrands )) /(totalBrandCount) ;
    // }

    this.topBrandsRating = 0;
    this.lowBrandsRating = 0;
    this.overalRating = 0;
    const avg_num_votes = totalBrandCount/2;
    const avg_rating =  (TBS+LBS)/2;
    if(avg_num_votes !==0) {
        if(totalTopBrands!=0 ) {
             this.topBrandsRating = ((avg_rating * avg_num_votes) + (totalTopBrands * TBS) ) / ((totalBrandCount/2) + totalTopBrands);
        }
        if(totalLowBrands!=0 ) {
             this.lowBrandsRating = ((avg_rating * avg_num_votes) + (totalLowBrands * LBS) ) / ((totalBrandCount/2) + totalLowBrands);
        }
        this.overalRating = ((TBS * this.topBrandsRating) + ( LBS * this.lowBrandsRating )) /(this.lowBrandsRating+this.topBrandsRating) ;
    }`
```

I understand my question is not that clear , please comment on this so that I can explain more about this.

Comment: If you already know that your question is not clear enough, then why don't you try to improve it? Explain what a rating is (is it a number?), explain how the overall rating is calculated, explain what you want to calculate and how your current approach works.

Comment: You are right @NicoSchertler, I need to improve, so here are details, I want to normalize count number ( between 0 to 5 ) .  With the help of google I get total brands count available in particular area. Now depending on the number of brands count( both  high brands and low brands) I need to rate the area between 0 to 5 . 5 means high brand area. Currently even If I get one brand it says high brand area. I  understand I should have some min rating count to jump into this calculation. I want to know is there any math formula to do systemically

Comment: Please use the edit button to add such details. Here is what I understand: You have a number of areas and each area has a number of high brands and a number of low brands. And from these two counts, you want to calculate an area rating that reflects these counts. Is this correct? How do you want this rating to behave? E.g. rating should be 1 if all brands are low and 5 if all brands are high?

Comment: Thanks @NicoSchertler for quick reply,  Yes you got me correct. Generally people think  if area has more high brand it means it expensive and rich area and visa versa. My problem is having one top brand doesn't mean its expensive and same with low brand as well. I want to arrive to formula which helps me to rate these area by number of high and low brand count. There are many maths algorithms  , but not able to figure it out which one fits here.

Comment: How about `3 + (highBrandCount - lowBrandCount) * factor` and cut off at 1 and 3? Or maybe using the [sigmoid function](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoidfunktion) on the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the  suggestion. This sounds good but  it depends on 'factor' value. And in my case lowbrandcount can go as high as possible ( may 90,100,200  this is dynamic and unpredictable data & varies from place to place ) same with highBrandcount as well. Could you please tell me how to calculate the 'factor'? I think having the right formula for 'factor' would solve this issue . Difference between these highBrandCount & lowBrandCount  has to normalized between 0 to 1 .

Comment: @NicoSchertler, I think it is time to convert your comments into an answer so people can really upvote it. Ullas, have you looked at the sigmoid function idea? [English wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) contains also references to a few other similarly shaped functions.

Comment: Can the factor be an adjustable parameter? How would you do it manually? What would be the rating of an area with 1 high brand, 2, 10, 100...?

Comment: @NicoSchertler , that is where I stuck . Just in general how do we rate area with one top brand ? If I find only one high brand I will rate is 2.5 and if I find only one low brand I rather ignore that . I will consider low brand only if its greater than 3 . And one more than if I get 0 high brand and more low brand rating will go high. I want to consider both count to rate the area. Its tricky when  the difference between two goes large.

Comment: You need to define the desired behavior first. This is not something we can help you with. You are the only one who knows the requirements.

Comment: Thanks @NicoSchertler for all your inputs, I found way to do this. Currently I am evaluating with different set of data . Once I am done with it will share the answer.